# What is the fastest way to initialize an immutable unboxed int array in Haskell?

Tags: arrays, haskell

Is this the fastest way to initialize an immutable array in Haskell with non-default (non-zero) values? In the following examples I am simply initializing the array with values from 0 to (size-1).

Fastest so far (twice the speed of Code.ST below). Thanks to *leftaroundabout*:

```
...
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

stArray :: Int -> V.Vector Int
stArray size =
    V.generate size id
...
```

My original fastest:

```
module Code.ST where

import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

stArray :: Int -> UArray Int Int
stArray size =
    runSTUArray $ newArray (0,size-1) 0 >>= f 0
    where
        f i a
         | i >= size = return a
         | otherwise = writeArray a i i >> f (i + 1) a

stMain :: IO ()
stMain = do
    let size    = 340000000
    let a       = stArray size
    putStrLn $ "Size: " ++ show size ++ " Min: " ++ show (a ! 0) ++ " Max: " ++ show (a ! (size - 1))
```

I have tried the simpler immutable ways of doing it and it is 2 to 3 times slower on my PC (YMMV). I also tried Repa but it falls over even with smaller than 340000000 size arrays (lots of HD trashing - I gave up before it finished).

Comment: I reckon fastest would be to switch to `Data.Vector.Unboxed`, simply `stArray size = generate size id`.

Comment: leftaroundabout: Yep you are right. Data.Vector.Unboxed is twice as fast. I will accept your answer if you turn it into one :-)

Comment: How does `Data.Vector.Unboxed.generate` compare?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `listArray` from `Data.Array.Unboxed`? You can use them like this:

```
-- listArray :: (Ix i, IArray a e) => (i, i) -> [e] -> a i e
listArray (0,3) "abcdefgh" :: UArray Int Char
```

This will create

```
array (0,3) [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'),(3,'d')]
```

If you need a bit more flexibility you can use `array` from the same module.

```
-- array :: (Ix i, IArray a e) => (i, i) -> [(i, e)] -> a i e
array (0,3) (zip [1,3,0,2] "abcd") :: UArray Int Char
```

Which will produce

```
array (0,3) [(0,'c'),(1,'a'),(2,'d'),(3,'b')]
```

I don't really know whether it is fast or not, but certainly it is more convenient to use than hand-written ST loops.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and listArray is 2 to 3 times slower. I would prefer to not write ST loops but in this case speed is more important than convenience.

Comment: On my machine your example written with `listArray` is only about 1.5 times slower than ST. It is certainly not twice as slow. ;)

Comment: It is on my PC :-) Actual numbers depends a *lot* on your specific CPU, CPU cache size, memory size/speed etc. so YMMV.